# Unknown Question mark in taxonomy url WP

Tags: wordpress

I have added a custom taxonomy under a custom post type programmatically...Everything is working well but when i am using any russian language like: `Преподаватель` it is being added but when i want to go to the url it looks like: `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=ec-�������������&post_type=event`

What are these sign marks?this seems to be very weired.I have re-saved permalink and changed language to russian.but not working yet

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a URL in the WP admin area. WordPress will urlencode the names of taxonomy terms just like any other URL so it is valid URL syntax. I think the takeaway is that your browser does not know what to do with those symbols after they are urlencod-ed so it shows that `?` glyph. Wouldn't worry about if WP is functioning as expected.